# Excel SUMIfs with OR and SUMProduct

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, sumifs

I have 3 set of conditions listed below, 2 in each set

```
SUMIFS(TotalColumn,
      ColumnA,>1,ColumnA,<5,
      ColumnB,>1,ColumnB,<5,
      ColumnC,>1,ColumnC,<5)
```

I am trying replace the 3rd set with multiple OR conditions

```
SUMIFS(TotalColumn,
      ColumnA,>1,ColumnA,<5,
      ColumnB,>1,ColumnB,<5,
     (ColumnC,>1,ColumnC,<5)OR(ColumnC,>17,ColumnC,<20),(ColumnC,>100,ColumnC,<120))
```

What is the best was to achieve the above while avoiding multiple sumifs; `sumif()+sumifs()+sumifs()`

I haven't been to get this to work using `SUM(SUMIFS` with `{}` on the 3rd set

```
SUM(SUMIFS(TotalColumn,
      ColumnA,>1,ColumnA,<5,
      ColumnB,>1,ColumnB,<5
    {(ColumnC,>1,ColumnC,<5)},{(ColumnC,>17,ColumnC,<20)},{(ColumnC,>100,ColumnC,<120})))
```

Will appreciate help with the `{}` or another sumproduct trick without an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i'm interpreting your thirs set correctly; 3 possible cobinations of values of column C?
You'll have to hit `Ctrl + Shift + Ent` since this is an array function:

```
SUM(TOTAL*
    (ColumnA>1)*
    (ColumnA<5)*
    (ColumnB>1)*
    (ColumnB<5)*
    (OR
    (AND(ColumnC>1,ColumnC<5),
    AND(ColumnC,>17,ColumnC,<20),
    (ColumnC,>100,ColumnC,<120)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, will test when I get home, answer should return additions including of any possible combination of the 3rd set I.e (where ColumnC >1 and <5)+ (where ColumnC >17 and <20) + etc